# Dell Motherboard failures - condensation?

Tags: dell, airflow

Since April 2018 I've had multiple motherboard failure on my Dell servers (at least 12).

We've operated dell servers in this location for over 20 years without a problem. Since April however its been non stop problems.  The one environmental change that I know of is that around that time the tenant underneath our office moved out.  So that office is no longer heated / cooled beyond the minimum.

Here is my rack setup.

We have 4 Dell servers rack mounted. These are various models.

The rack is in a room that is climate controlled. it receives air from both the buildings central A/C  plus it has its own A/C unit within 10 feet of the rack.

The rack also has a UPS which is connected to a power line conditioner. The rack is grounded.  Also in the rack is a KVM switch , a monitor and a surge protector for the equipment that is not connected to the UPS.

The temp in the room is in the range of 68 - 71 degrees.
The standalone A/C also removes humidity.

We've recently added an additional dehumidifier.  The humidity range is 22 to 34 currently.

Most of the failures show up with the PG voltage out of range error.

I've changed out the UPS and surge protector and KVM after this started happening and added the rack ground.  The problems persist so I don't think its electrical.

On several failures we've noticed one or two drops of fluid (water?) on the motherboards underneath the air vents on  the cover.   On others we see what looks like corrosion on the back of the board itself.

My conclusion is that condensation is causing this problem.

Does this sound correct?

What steps should be taken to prevent further problems?

thanks

Comment: Glance up at the ceiling and make sure there isn't a water leak.

Comment: No water leak . If there was I’d see it on the rack and the other equipment close to the top. Everything looks dry

Comment: This is one of those things where a picture of the “water” and corrosion would be worth a thousand words. What you’re saying really doesn’t add up, so we have to assume something in the content of your question is inaccurate and it would help for us to be able to double check the facts. Such as what are you really seeing on the motherboards. Who else has access to this closet? Is it possible someone is sabotaging the equipment? Sounds like someone is literally spraying water in the vents.

Comment: I'll post a picture tomorrow. We are a small group of developers.  The room is open i.e. no access control.  I have a hard time believing someone is sabotaging the equipment.